# mysql query on Group fails

Tags: sql, mysql

In a part of my sql query at the end of the query I have this

```
GROUP BY
`Record`.`RecordID`
ORDER BY
`Record`.`RecordID`
```

it works fine until I have RecordID null, and then mysql query fails. Is there a way around that IFNULL I dont use GROUP BY and Order BY

thank

Comment: Fails how? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
GROUP BY IFNULL(`Record`.`RecordID`,0)
```

You can skip the `ORDER BY`, since by default MySql will sort based on the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @cyberkiwi Worst comment that i have seen today... did you say undocumented? **"In MySQL, GROUP BY is used for sorting"** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: you are right, but the more appropriate page would have been http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html `By default, MySQL sorts all GROUP BY col1, col2, ... queries as if you specified ORDER BY col1, col2,`

Comment: Oracle 10g introduced a new group-by mechanism when "order by" is missing (hashing rather than sorting). Please don't repeat the same mistake I did (omitted order by). If you need the result sorted, specify ORDER BY.

Comment: FYI from the [mysql 5.7 changelog](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html) `Relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting in MySQL 5.7 is deprecated`

Answer (score 0):

When you say fail, what do you mean?

If I have the table:

```
 Value
   a
   b
 {null}
   c
   c
```

and I run the query:

```
select value from table
group by value
```

Your result is:

```
{null}
a
b
c
```

To get rid of the nulls:

```
select value from table
group by value
having value is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the GROUP BY and ORDER BY clauses **in and of themselves** can cause anything to fail.  Please don't show just some part that you think is broken, if you knew better, you wouldn't need to ask here right?

Add a IS NOT NULL filter to remove them entirely

```
WHERE `Record`.`RecordID` is not null
GROUP BY
`Record`.`RecordID`
ORDER BY
`Record`.`RecordID`
```